# Google cloud TPU: NotImplementedError: Non-resource Variables are not supported inside TPU computations

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tpu

I am trying to train my model using google cloud's TPUs. The model works fine on CPU and GPU, and I can run the TPU tutorials without any problems (so it is not a problem of connecting to TPUs). However, when I run my program on the TPU cloud I get an error. The most important line is probably the following:

```
NotImplementedError: Non-resource Variables are not supported inside TPU computations (operator name: training_op/update_2nd_caps/primary_to_first_fc/W/ApplyAdam/RefEnter)
```

And here is the full error in case there is something important there:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TPU_playground.py", line 85, in <module>
    capser.train(input_fn=train_input_fn_tpu, steps=n_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 366, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1119, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1132, in _train_model_default
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 1992, in _call_model_fn
    features, labels, mode, config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1107, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2223, in _model_fn
    _train_on_tpu_system(ctx, model_fn_wrapper, dequeue_fn))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2537, in _train_on_tpu_system
    device_assignment=ctx.device_assignment)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu.py", line 733, in shard
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu.py", line 394, in replicate
    device_assignment, name)[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu.py", line 546, in split_compile_and_replicate
    outputs = computation(*computation_inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2530, in multi_tpu_train_steps_on_single_shard
    single_tpu_train_step, [_INITIAL_LOSS])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/training_loop.py", line 207, in repeat
    cond, body_wrapper, inputs=inputs, infeed_queue=infeed_queue, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/training_loop.py", line 169, in while_loop
    name="")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 3209, in while_loop
    result = loop_context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2941, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2878, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/training_loop.py", line 120, in body_wrapper
    outputs = body(*(inputs + dequeue_ops))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/training_loop.py", line 203, in body_wrapper
    return [i + 1] + _convert_to_list(body(*args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 1166, in train_step
    self._call_model_fn(features, labels))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 1337, in _call_model_fn
    estimator_spec = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/home/adrien_doerig/capser/capser_7_model_fn.py", line 100, in model_fn_tpu
    **output_decoder_deconv_params)
  File "/home/adrien_doerig/capser/capser_model.py", line 341, in capser_model
    loss_training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step(), name="training_op")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 409, in minimize
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_optimizer.py", line 114, in apply_gradients
    return self._opt.apply_gradients(summed_grads_and_vars, global_step, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 602, in apply_gradients
    update_ops.append(processor.update_op(self, grad))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 113, in update_op
    update_op = optimizer._apply_dense(g, self._v)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py", line 148, in _apply_dense
    grad, use_locking=self._use_locking).op
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/gen_training_ops.py", line 293, in apply_adam
    use_nesterov=use_nesterov, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1782, in __init__
    self._control_flow_post_processing()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1793, in _control_flow_post_processing
    self._control_flow_context.AddOp(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2430, in AddOp
    self._AddOpInternal(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2451, in _AddOpInternal
    real_x = self.AddValue(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2398, in AddValue
    self._outer_context.AddInnerOp(enter.op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu.py", line 310, in AddInnerOp
    self._AddOpInternal(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu.py", line 287, in _AddOpInternal
    "(operator name: %s)" % op.name)
NotImplementedError: Non-resource Variables are not supported inside TPU computations (operator name: training_op/update_2nd_caps/primary_to_first_fc/W/ApplyAdam/RefEnter)
```

It seems that the forward pass of the graph is built fine, but the backprop using AdamOptimizer is not supported by the TPUs in this case. I tried using more standard optimizers (GradientDescentOptimizer and MomentumOptimizer) but it doesn't help. All the tensors in the feedforward pass are in formats compatible with TPUs (i.e. tf.float32).

Does anyone have suggestions as to what I should try?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of TensorFlow are you using on Cloud TPU?
Can you run

`python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.VERSION)"`

to find out? (Some routes to creating a Cloud TPU, such as `ctpu up`, create one with the default, latest version of TensorFlow, so that might not be obvious).

Is there a minimal script that I can run to repro this failure?

Comment: The problem is that the code is pretty huge and entangled, so there is no way to easily reproduce the error. Luckily, I have found a solution (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to use the TPUs without using the `ctpu up` command, which solves the problem. I simply do everything exactly as I would do it to run my code on cloud GPUs:

-- see documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction
-- a simple explanatory video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_d4bEKUG2Q

BUT, the ONLY DIFFERENCE is that I use `--scale-tier 'BASIC_TPU'` instead of `--scale-tier 'STANDARD_1'` when I run my job. So the command to run the job is

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME --module-name capser.capser_7_multi_gpu --package-path ./capser --job-dir=gs://capser-data/$JOB_NAME --scale-tier 'BASIC_TPU' --stream-logs --runtime-version 1.9
 --region us-central1
```

(I previously define the variable $JOB_NAME: `export JOB_NAME=<input your job name>`)

Also, make sure you choose a region which has TPUs! us-central1 works for example.

So maybe it is a small bug when using ctpu up, but it seems not to be a problem when using the above method. I hope that helps!

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is expected behavior. CMLE provisions the resources necessary to exec your training jobs and in this way provides a managed UX. On the other hand, `ctpu` is useful for _interactive_ work with TPU, which can be useful when iterating against the TPU Node.